# Loop through user defined Sheets in a workbook

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

Please check my problem...

About the workbook: It has 13 sheets Sheet1 is "Master" and the rest 12 are named as month "Apr","May"...etc...till "Mar".....

In the "master" sheet user can defined the month he wants to format..User can defined values like("Apr","NA","Mar")... the code should read this values enter by user and format the Sheets ONLY that match month name and skip NA.

What the Code Should do:

1) VBA should check the values in cells O7 to O18 which are user defined values like (Apr,Mar,Jan,NA)

2) The code should then go to the worksheet with names apr to mar and skip NA..

```
Sub Copyd()
Dim apr As String
Dim may As String
    'Similarly for all the months till mar'
apr = Cells(7, 15).Value
may = Cells(8, 15).Value
    'Assigned cell value for all the month till mar(Cell contains values
     'like (Ex: apr,jan,NA) which are user defined
Dim Months As Variant
Dim Month As Variant
Months = Array(jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, _
     aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
ActiveSheet.Name = Months
For Each Month In Months
   'formatting code here
Next Month
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked better according to my case.

```
Sub Copyd()
Sheets("Master").Select
Dim apr As String
Dim may As String

    'Similarly for all the months till mar'

apr = Cells(4, 56).Value
may = Cells(5, 56).Value

    'Assigned cell value for all the month till mar(Cell contains values
    'like: apr,jan,NA) which are user defined

Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To 13
With Sheets(i).Activate

If ActiveSheet.Name = apr Then
Call test
ActiveSheet.Name = apr
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Else
On Error Resume Next
End If

If ActiveSheet.Name = may Then
Call test
ActiveSheet.Name = may
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Else
On Error Resume Next
End If

   'Similarly for all the months till mar'

End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim wshSrc As Worksheet, wshDst As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, wshName As String

On Error Resume Next

Set wshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
For i = 7 to 18
    wshName = wshSrc.Range("O" & i)
    Set wshDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wshName)
    If Err.Number = 9 'worksheet does not exists (NA)
        Err.Clear()
        Goto SkipNext
    End If
    'here code to copy id's
SkipNext:    '
Next
```

Comment: @Haider, you're very welcome. Can you accept my answer as a solution? Cheers, Maciej